# Different responses for globally handling http 404 not found error ; for Ajax & non-Ajax requests

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I need to handle http 404 errors inside my asp.net mvc web application. and for ajax requests to show an alert , while for non-ajax requests to redirect to an action method. for example one of the action methods looks as follow:-

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
      {

      var link=     await unitofwork.SkillRepository.FindLinkToKB(id.Value);
      if (link == null)
              {
                  return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404, "The link has already been deleted.");
              }
```

now inside the web.config i wrote the following to redirect to /Home/Error when an http 404 is raised:-

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error path="/Home/Error" statusCode="404" responseMode="Redirect"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

and inside the ajax-setup i wrote the following:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (xhr.status == 401)
            window.location = "/Account/Login";
        else if (xhr.status == 403 || xhr.status == 404)
            alert(xhr.statusText, 'Error');

        $(".loadingimage").hide();
    });
```

but the problem i am facing is that i will always be redirected to the `"/Home/Error"` action method when a 404 error is raised for ajax and non-ajax requests, so seems the ajax-setup will be ignored. so how i can have different responses for the http 404 error based on the request type (if it is an ajax or non-ajax request ? ) ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe take out the redirect in your web.config and handle it in the controller/action, for example (pseudo code) if HttpStatus = 404 than redirect to /Home/Error.

Comment: so where exactly i need to add the check "if HttpStatus = 404 than redirect to /Home/Error" ??

Comment: Looking at your action again, it seems you already have a check to see if the link is null, so instead of returning the HttpStatus you could send them to the error page there.

Comment: yes but i am looking at a more standard way to handle the error ... not sure if this can be achieved ...

Comment: Not sure either since 404 is already being handled globally in your config, I don't know of a way to override that with your AJAX call. I'll upvote and maybe someone with more experience than I have will come along and provide some more help.